# ECONNRESET when having high number of tcp connections in Node

Tags: node.js, macos, sockets, tcp

I have a Node.js app consisting of a server and client, which are communicating using a protocol on top of TCP. I implemented a simple load test for the app. Basically there are a bunch of clients connecting to the server and exchanging messages. It all works nicely up to about 600 clients, then I start to get ECONNRESET errors. To make sure that it is not the implementation I created a very simple TCP server/client where clients will just connect to the server. This works up to around 900 connections, but then it starts to give the same error. I am running this application on my Mac with Maverics. I already played around with sysctl and ulimit, but nothing worked. Here are the settings I changed:

- kern.ipc.somaxconn=12000
- kern.maxfilesperproc=12000
- kern.maxfiles=12000
- ulimit -S -n 12000

The simple TCP server/client implementation that I used is as follows:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 6969;

var server = net.createServer();
server.listen(PORT, HOST);
server.on('connection', function(sock) {
    console.log('New Client')
});


for(var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(PORT, HOST, function () {
        console.log('Connected');
    });
}
```

I am not sure if this problem is OS or Node related.